# Combining data from 2 tables in to 1 query

Tags: sql

**Hi all**

Im having some problems combining data from 2 tables in to 1 query.

Now I have one *table-nr1* with raw data of restaurants and in the other *table-nr2* I have a number of restaurants that have been graded.

So, now I want to select all restaurants and at the same time select grades of that restaurant from *table-nr2* and get the average value of those grades.

How can I do this in a single SQL query?

Comment: Please could you provide descriptions of your database tables.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  r.*,
        COALESCE(
        (
        SELECT  AVG(grade)
        FROM    table_nr2 g
        WHERE   g.restaurant_id = r.id
        ), 0)
FROM    table-nr1 r
```

Comment: +1 for interesting alternative. Although for what its worth I usually avoid using sub query in select clauses.

Comment: @Conrad: could you please explain why would you avoid the subqueries?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your restaurants have a name and id, and the your reviews have a grade

```
SELECT re.name, avg(ra.grade)
FROM table-nr1 re
LEFT JOIN table-nr2 ra ON re.id = ra.id
GROUP BY re.name
```

You need to group by all fields you want to select which are not aggregated, and left join means you will get all restaurants, irrespective of whether they have any ratings.

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform a join.  In this case an inner left join sounds fine, which is the default join.  You can use USING syntax if the field that links them is the same on both sides, so you would end up with something like this:

```
SELECT table-nr1.*, AVG(table-nr2.score)
FROM table-nr1
JOIN table-nr2 USING (restrauntId)
```

Otherwise you could do something that links them using an on clause like this:

```
SELECT table-nr1.*, AVG(table-nr2.score)
FROM table-nr1
JOIN table-nr2 ON (table-nr1.restrauntId = table-nr2.restrauntId)
```

Comment: I'm not sure about your statement that inner left join is the default join type, you can either have a LEFT OUTER JOIN or an INNER JOIN, LEFT & RIGHT joins are used to specify which of the two tables being joined should return rows when no matching row in the other table is found

Comment: True... guess I just wasn't thinking this morning... it would simply be an inner join... which is the default when you say JOIN.